# Why are breakers tripping in my travel trailer?

Tags: circuit-breaker

I live in a travel trailer. It uses a system that reduces 120 VAC to 13.6 volts D.C. The owner of that trailer also made some modifications.

I have some 120 VAC outlets. I use two heaters that draw 12.5 amps each.
The 30 amp fuse keeps tripping. It should not be tripping.

The outside breaker box has a 50 am main breaker and a 20 amp and 30 amp breakers that feed off that one.

https://imgur.com/a/E49DBbJ

https://imgur.com/a/GH6Cp3i

https://imgur.com/a/3UN2JbS

What is going on?

Comment: Mentioning "some modifications" without telling us what they are isn't helpful.

Comment: The fact that you have a 30 amp breaker serving 120 volt outlets is concerning, too. Please revise to add more detail about the circuitry.

Comment: I bet that circuit with the 30 amps does not use 10 gauge wire.  If it even uses 12 gauge will be surprising.  You might be living in a fire just waiting to happen.

Comment: *The 30 amp fuse keeps tripping* Fuses don't "trip". They "blow" and then require replacement. So are you referring to an actual fuse, to the 30A *breaker* outside (the 50/30/20 box) or a 30A breaker inside your trailer? Also, what else (AC or DC that is produced from the AC) is running at the same time? Even if 25A for the heaters is correct, it would only take another 5A (or so, see "trip curve") to start tripping a 30A breaker.

Comment: Trailers are weird and can have a 30 amp TT-30 connection serving 120V outlets.

Comment: Regardless of how much current is drawn vs breaker rating, if the wires are too small they will heat excessively, and heat alone will trip the breaker, even if it's carrying less than rated amps.

Comment: That's 25a if there's no voltage drop, which there is. And if it's tripping-safe at ~27 because it's old, then that's just the deal. Wouldn't surprise me if it popped with everything having been made *today*, with no extension cords and no modifications.

Comment: In the pictures, the 30 amp appears to be the main breaker. This means the cumulative load (all circuits, including 12 v), are drawing more than 30 amps. Isolate off the water heater and converter (12v) and check. Then isolate others. The safe thing here is to use a clamp meter to measure draw on each circuit as you turn it on (they are cheap these days). Otherwise you are relying on the 30 amp to trip to tell you which loads are too much, with no idea of what the individual loads are. Not a safe way to problem solve.

Comment: We still need more info - there are both 30A breakers and 30A fuses in your setup and we don't know which are tripping or blowing. The trailer panel seems to have the 30A breaker feeding the 12V inverter and all the 12V stuff has fuses. There are also other 120V breakers that feed the water heater and A/C etc. Not sure which outlets you are powering the heaters from. The whole trailer panel should be feed by the 50A breaker in the external breaker box you mention, a picture of that would be helpful

Comment: The GFCI in the bathroom is what I use for one of my electric heaters. I have the heater plugged into a toggle switch. That way I don't have to unplug it. I noticed that that switch gets pretty warm. My conclusion is that the wiring is not designed for continuous use of the heater. So I only run one heater at a time. Either the bedroom heater or the heater for the kitchen area.

Answer (score 1):

There's two possibilities here.

One: the 30A breaker has a problem, resulting in it tripping under a much lower load. This is more common than you might think. It's still relatively rare.

Two: you are actually drawing more than 30A, possibly quite a bit more. If that's happening this is a dangerous situation, and you need to fix it right now.

You can't tell which of these it is without some form of measurement. What this means you need is a current meter. The easiest way to go for measuring 30A circuits is to get a clamp ammeter. It will need to be clamped around a single leg of your circuit, either the neutral or the hot lead. Since there is the slight possibility of current heading to ground, and the breaker only measures power on the hot lead, clamping the hot lead will be the most accurate. Clamping that lead will require either access inside the breaker panel, or a breakout cable. I don't know of anyone who makes a TT-30 breakout cable, so if you don't have access to the panel you will have to build one using three wires, a TT-30 plug, and a TT-30 receptacle. They are kind of dangerous so don't use it permanently.

Once you can measure current you can determine the fault. First, validate that you're not drawing more than 30A. If you're drawing under 30A and the breaker is popping, you've found your problem. Replace the breaker. If you're drawing over 30A, start turning off devices until you are under that number. Given that some of your load is heating, you might need to target 24A or less to guarantee that you won't have breaker trips.

Not exactly part of the answer: if you do need more current than the TT-30 can reliably provide, you might need to move one of your loads to the 20A outlet. An example might be connecting the battery charger that provides your 13.6V directly to the 20A, leaving the TT-30 for your heating loads. Also: heating loads are dangerous, particularly if this is old trailer wiring. Check outlets and connections regularly. Whenever possible, don't run heating when you're asleep or out, as there's a risk of fire. And please make sure you have two working smoke detectors.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact you're right. I thought I was getting too preachy but it honestly belongs. I moved it into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The 30 amp breaker (I assume a single pole) should feed this type of receptacle: [image]

I would not expect your heaters, apparently rated at 15 amps, to be run off this circuit designed to protect a 30 amp device.

Are the heaters connected to the 30 amp breaker, or is something else.

If they are, consider changing breaker and receptacle to 20 amp and only using one heater (or one rated for 16 amps). Or change out the two heaters for one rated for 120v-24 amps.

In your current layout, if you have a problem with one of the smaller heaters, that isn't a full short, the plug wires could become heating elements themselves.

If something else is connected to the 30 amp breaker, look there for the problem.

The most important thing is to stay safe and not over-power your devices.